# Extend Intent to change look and extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

When I launch my Intents I want to add a textfield at the bottom where the user get a default file name that they can change. I want this behaviour both for Camera and file picker.

This is how I launch my Intents now.

```
private void takeOrSelectPhoto() {
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
    pickIntent.setType("image/*");
    pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, CAMERA_TEMP_FILE_URI);

    String pickTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.select_or_take_picture);
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
    chooserIntent.putExtra
            (
                    Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent }
            );
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And this is how I grab the picture later.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Save image to sdcard 
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to extend the event or will I have to do this in a completely different way? If so can I please get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in bundle to intent when you send activity.

Answer (score -1):

You can't extends intent in order to affect other activities (like the Gallery).

When an Activity gets the intent, it tries to read only the elements that are relevant to the activity. For example, the Gallery Activity will not be aware if you try to add add a string extra with key "this_is_a_key_test" to your intent.

You first need to handle this additional data in your activity and only then you can use it in the intent.